# Kubernetes Go operator blocks on client.Get() secret data

Tags: go, kubernetes, secret-key, operator-sdk

Trying to read the secret data in operator Reconcile function.

```
secret := &corev1.Secret{}
reqLogger.Info("Before get secret")
err = r.client.Get(context.TODO(), secretNamespaceName, secret)
reqLogger.Info("After get secret")
```

Actual Output :
The output shows that the Get secret call blocks on client.Get()

- "Before get secret" displayed
- "After get secret" not displayed.

Expected Output :
I was expecting that get call return successfully and "After get secret" message should display.

```
Added following markers in controller, But still not worked.
//+kubebuilder:rbac:groups="",resources=secrets,verbs=get;list;patch;update;watch

// +kubebuilder:rbac:groups=security.openshift.io, resources=securitycontextconstraints, resourceNames=privileged, verbs=use
```

Comment: Is there any panic? If not, log the `err=..` too.

Comment: I added below logs,
if err != nil {
                reqLogger.Error(err, "Error while getting the secrets")
                return ctrl.Result{}, err
        }

There is no Panic, client.Get() call never returns. I tried to give incorrect name/namespace, then also client.Get() never returns.
Is there any issue at kube API server for getting secrets? or Any extra configuration to do.

Other client.Get() for  PVC/PV returns immediately with correct output.